# Debug Handle-Based Custom Memory Management in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have written some code to do custom memory management. Due to my function aimed to do memory defragmentation, some of the memory might be moved. So I used handle to represent each memory allocated. However, this seems to have become an issue when I am writing containers using the custom memory management (which represent the space it allocated with handle). For example, I cannot see a way to force the debugger to show the contents of my vector as the way it shows `std::vector`. Is there anyway to achieve that?

I tried Visual Studio `natvis` but the step to get an address from a handle is a function, which `natvis` does not support. I also tried to make a function just for the purpose of debugging, in which I copied the contents in the container to a `std::vector` and return it. Then I tried to evaluate the function in debugger, but it did not give me anything.

Comment: Sounds like hard work.  What is your use-case?

Comment: @PaulSanders I use the memory management for the game engine I am building. For the handle, I am planning on using it almost everywhere in the engine for the part of codes requires dynamic allocation before.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the built in memory management services?  Specifically, how do you know they're not good enough?

Comment: @PaulSanders I do not oppose the idea of using built-in memory management service. But custom memory management service is faster and has more purposes than just speed. I would need to build a custom one sometime anyway and I would prefer to do it earlier than later. If I do not, at a later point, I would have to replace all allocations in my code and that could be very messy. I am simply trying to figure out how to do it in a proper and easy-to-use way.

Comment: I still think you're wasting your time, developers who are way smarter than us spend a lot of time optimising this stuff.  You might like to take a look at this (it's enabled by default from Vista on): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/low-fragmentation-heap

Comment: @PaulSanders I got the idea of making my custom memory management from reading Section 6.2 from the book Game Engine Architecture. In there it says `malloc` and `free` or `new` and `delete` are typically slow because of 2 reasons: 1. They are general-purpose facility, used to handle any allocation size. 2. They usually involves context-switch from user mode into kernel mode before allocation. 
Do you think these are still true?

Comment: There's certainly a trade-off, yes, but I don't think #2 is true in most implementations.  Anyway, you could put your allocator behind your own API and just write a naive implementation for now, see how you go.  If it proves to be a bottleneck you can then look to improve it (one simple idea I can think of is to create your own, non-serialised heap if you don't need it to be threadsafe).  BUT, don't cut yourself off from the Standard Library containers, especially `std::vector`.  If you do, you'll come to regret it.  [more]

Comment: These all take a custom allocator as an extra template parameter, but you can't implement your 'self-defragmenting' memory idea that way.  But honestly, I would simply drop that, it's likely to make your game stutter anyway.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you for your comments. I will have a go with the built-in memory allocation. I will also keep this question open since I really want to know how everything works when handles are used. Or is handle an overall bad idea?

Comment: Memory that moves around (in user space) is a total pain.  I've had to deal with that in the past and it's not good. Be prepared for lots of subtle bugs.

Comment: Before rolling your own memory allocation strategy, you might also want to look at eg [mimalloc](https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc), which is a drop in replacement for `malloc`. One of its promises is to reduce fragmentation. Afaik, it also reduces the necessary context switches. There are also other similar projects available.